# React JS (Bootstrap) form saves every input in local storage instead of using onSubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-bootstrap

New to React JS here and trying to make a form (that's in a modal) to save the submit of a text input and text area to local storage. The value of these 2 input are mapped to my Form State. My Form Component has a button with onSubmit function that should send the object to local storage, once *the user clicks it*. But what happens is that it saves every letter that I type as a separate entry to local storage and not the whole thing when user clicks the button. What am I doing wrong here?

So suppose I want to save `{name: "oatmeal", ingredients: ["milk, "oat"]}`, it saves:

```
{name: "o", ingredients: []}
{name: "oa", ingredients: []}
{name: "oat", ingredients: []}
```

etc. as I type....

Here is my code:

```
var App = React.createClass({


  render: function(){

    return( 

      <div className="container">
        <h1>Recipe Box</h1>
        <AddRecipeButton />
      </div>

    )  

  }


});


var AddRecipeButton = React.createClass({


  getInitialState(){


    return {showModal: false};

  },

  close: function(){

    this.setState({showModal:false});

  },

  open: function(){

    this.setState({showModal:true});

  },

  render: function(){ 

    return (

      <div>
        <Button bsStyle="warning" bsSize="large" onClick={this.open}>
            Add Recipe
        </Button>
        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Add a Recipe Here</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <Form />
            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </div>


      )
  }

});

var Form = React.createClass({

  getInitialState(){


    return {

      name: "", 

      ingredients: [ ]

    };

  },

  getValidationStateName(){

    var length = this.state.name.length;

    if(length > 0) {

      return "success";

    } else {

      return "error";

    }

  },

  getValidationStateIngredients(){

    var length = this.state.ingredients.length;

    if(length > 0){

      return "success";

    } else {

      return "error";

    }


  },

  handleInput: function(key,e){


    var input = e.target.value;


    if(key === "ingredients"){

        input = e.target.value.split(",");  

    }

    var update = {};
    //create object to merge with state

    update[key] = input;
    //set the value of input field to update object

    console.log(update);

    this.setState(update, function(){
    //merge the object into the state  

      console.log(this.state);

    });


  },

  handleSubmit(){

    var recipe = JSON.stringify(this.state);

    localStorage.setItem(this.state.name, recipe);

  },

  render: function(){


    return (

      <form>
        <FormGroup controlId="formNameText" validationState = {this.getValidationStateName()}>
          <ControlLabel>Recipe</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Give your recipe a name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onInput={this.handleInput.bind(this,'name')}
            />
          <FormControl.Feedback /> 
        </FormGroup>  
          <br/>
        <FormGroup controlId="formIngredientsTextarea" validationState = {this.getValidationStateIngredients()}>
          <FormControl
            componentClass="textarea"
            placeholder="Insert your ingredients, separated by a comma"
            value={this.state.ingredients}
            onInput={this.handleInput.bind(this,'ingredients')}
          />  
          <FormControl.Feedback /> 
          <hr/>
        </FormGroup>
        <Button bsStyle="primary"  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</Button>
      </form>  


    );

  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<Button bsStyle="primary"  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</Button>` to `<Button bsStyle="primary"  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</Button>`

Comment: I changed it to this `<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</Button>`, that works. Why do I need to use bind(this)?

Comment: To make `this` to point to the `Form` class inside `handleSubmit` method, so you can do `this.setState`. Otherwise `this` will point to the event target and you'll get another type of error.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this,

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</Button>
```

You will actually invoke the function `handleSubmit()` on each render, instead you should only pass the function prototype.

```
<Button bsStyle="primary" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
```

*Nota Bene*: You won't need `.bind(this)` here on component methods (unless you want to invoke them with parameters `.bind(this, params)`) when your component is created using `React.createClass`; the component methods are auto bound by React.

Comment: Ok, got it! However, it doesnt work with onSubmit, but does work with onClick like so  `<Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>`. Do you maybe know why?

Comment: What exactly is happening when you click the button? Are you getting any errors?